# Change the edgecolor of single bar in bar plot through time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, matplotlib

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df_

Daily Risk Score    Green   Orange  Red
Date            
2020-07-08  505 150 22
2020-07-09  624 36  17
2020-07-10  611 41  25
2020-07-11  625 30  22
2020-07-12  635 25  17
2020-07-13  595 51  31
2020-07-14  509 121 47
2020-07-15  501 143 33
2020-07-16  489 164 24
2020-07-17  465 187 25
2020-07-18  482 167 28
2020-07-19  503 143 31
2020-07-20  500 148 29
2020-07-21  491 158 28
date_list=pd.date_range(today, (today+dt.timedelta(days=13)), freq='D').strftime('%d %b')
```

I then create a stacked bar plot using matplotlib:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16,12))
plot_day=dt.date.today().strftime('%d %b')
plt.bar(date_list, df_['Green'], color='green', zorder=10)
plt.bar(date_list, df_['Orange'], color='orange', bottom=df_['Green'], zorder=10)
plt.bar(date_list, df_['Red'], color='red', bottom=bars_new, zorder=10)
plt.grid(axis='y', zorder=0)
plt.axvline(x=plot_day, c='k', linestyle='--', zorder=11)
```

Currently, to indicate the current day I am using a vertical dashed line. However, I wanted to try changing the edgecolor to see if that made more of an impression. How can I just change the edgecolor of the entire bar for the current date (8 July)?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try passing the `edgecolor` and also use `df.plot.bar`:

```
today = pd.to_datetime('2020-07-08')
edge_colors = np.where(df.index==today, 'r', 'w')

df.plot.bar(stacked=True, width=0.8, edgecolor=edge_colors)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to do this using matplotlib plotting, as opposed to pandas? I already wrote the code to be used in matplotlib and it would be nice if there a solution with that geared in mind.

Comment: @EliTurasky just pass the same `edgecolor = edge_colors` into every single `plt.bar` command in your code. That said, I'm not sure why you wouldn't go for the `plot.bar()` solution. It's much more concise.